# Is there a JavaScript equivalent to "string" . "string" in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am currently learning a little bit of JavaScript and had a question.

In PHP, I am used to binding text and strings together with a simple dot like this:

```
echo "Text" . $String . "anotherText" . $anotherString
```

Is this possible in JavaScript? (Not the echo, but the binding of the strings and text.)

Comment: Just Googling tip: > `dot operator php` should result in the term *concatenation* -> `javascript concatenation` would have found your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript it's `+` instead of `.`

**Example 1:**

```
document.write("Text" + somestring + "anotherText" + anotherString);
```

**Example 2:**

```
alert("Text" + somestring + "anotherText" + anotherString);
```

**Example 3:**

```
var john = "Text" + somestring + "anotherText" + anotherString;
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`+` is the concatenation operator in JavaScript:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators)

```
"Text" + somestring + "anotherText" + anotherString;
```

Comment: i think `document.write` is unnecessary

Comment: `document.write` is more or less the JavaScript equivalent to `echo` in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes just, add:

```
'Text' + str + 'anotherText' + anotherString;
```